# Better way to organize multiple CSS code?

Tags: css

In my CSS code, I have this:

```
#feed .post:hover .rep {display:inline;}
#feed .post:hover .com {display:inline;}
#feed .post:hover .date {display:inline;}
```

Is there a way I could make it so rather than being 3 lines, it's all in one line? I tried doing

```
#feed .post:hover .rep, .com, .date {display:inline;}
```

But that didn't seem to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:-

```
#feed .post:hover .rep, #feed .post:hover .com, #feed .post:hover .date {display: inline}
```

Comment: Cool.  Make sure you mark the q as answered pls.  Glad to have helped